# Encryption between Angular 2 web pages and ASP.NET Core on the server

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cryptography

This is a very simple question because I haven't much experience in this field. I can use `Angular 2` Http calls and `ASP.NET Core Authorization and Authentication`. Is there any encryption of data between web page and the server for normal data flow without using SSL?

Comment: Of cource, but everything you do is easily broken, because all key material that you deliver to the browser cannot be trusted without TLS. Is this your actual question? If not and if you want to see some code, then this question is really too broad.

Comment: No.  Apart from the fact that web requests don't use SSL anymore (they use TLS, SSL has been deprecated by all browsers), Angular and ASP.NET Core expects that if you want a secure connection you will be using HTTPS

Comment: No, that is the purpose of TLS/HTTPS. The protocol prevents man in the middle attacks when data is being transferred from the server to the browser.

Comment: I think you have more or less answered my question. I was aware of HTTPS although I though thought it was SSL (many years ago I looked into it) How do I implement TLS/HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is TLS/HTTPS.
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b https://stackoverflow.com/users/61164/erik-funkenbusch and https://stackoverflow.com/users/896265/blake-mumford